# How to output the code itself?

Tags: algorithm, quine

How many ways are there to let the code output itself?

For example, write the code below,

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // some code
   }
}
```

to output itself

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // some code
   }
}
```

(Any programming language is accepted)

EDIT
This question has been answered in the historical posts,
search "quine" or check out https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=quine

Comment: Turning this into a community wiki would surely attract more volunteers.

Comment: Exact duplicate of many, many quine questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=quine

Comment: No problem.  Don't worry about deleting it - it will help others when they try to post the same question by showing up as a suggestion when they enter a new question title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called a programming quine, and has been extensively discussed on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=quine

Also see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm

http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/quine.html

-Adam

Answer (score 4):

look up [Quines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)).

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to read about quines.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)).

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hasn't this question [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105725/how-to-write-a-self-reproducing-code-prints-the-source-on-exec)?

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinite number ways to do this.  All you have to do is find one way and then add comments....